# How to get value from the merged excel cell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spreadsheet

[image]

Need help to get the merged cell value from "List Price Total" .
As shown in above image ,its a merged cell starting from row number 13 till 18 .
I am using below code to get the value but still getting it as null.

```
CellRangeAddress mergedCell = new CellRangeAddress(12, 17, 9, 9);
int rowNum = mergedCell.getFirstRow();
int lastRow = mergedCell.getLastRow();
int colIndex = mergedCell.getFirstColumn();
for (int rowCounter = rowNum; rowCounter < lastRow; rowCounter++) {
            Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(rowCounter).getCell(colIndex);
            cell2Update.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
            CellValue c = evaluator.evaluate(cell2Update);
            if (null != c) {
                Double lisPrice= c.getNumberValue();
                if (lisPrice> 0) {
                    spreadheetResultData.setListPricetotal(df.format(lisPrice));
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me out to get the merged cell value.

Comment: Generally for merged cells you need to fetch the top-left hand most cell for the real value

Comment: Its a J Column . So referring to the image , you mean to say value should be fetched from J13 . Tried that already, still failed !

Comment: Are you sure that's a single merged cell? from the image, actual value seems a bit too far from the `$` sign. It might be that the actual value is in column `K`? (although that's guess work as we cannot see the column names)

Comment: Yes I am sure . Its a single merged cell . from J13 to J18.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, just refer to the top left most cell, e.g if the range A2 to C4 is merged, then a formula of =A2 will return the contents of the merged cell, same applies with macros.

Comment: Just 1 column J + 6 rows 13 to 18 . Can I get the code to fetch the value out of J13 ...J18 ? I tried fetching J13, but still failed to get the value .

Comment: Sorry, what error did you get, not sure what you mean you failed to get the value, as mentioned by @Vityata you can select your merged cell to see that return cell, in another cell on the same sheet just preform the =J13 if this returns nothing, overwrite the value in the merged range just as a test to see what the formula returns.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the merged cell area;
2. Take a look in Excel which cell does it refer to (red arrow);
3. Refer this cell;

[image]

Comment: It says J13 but still value doesn't come . Can the issue be with formula evaluator ? as its formula cell .

Comment: @user3662369 - it can be. Try to write "Test" instead of the formula and give it a try. If it works, it is a formula issue.

Comment: but the formula is straight forward    =SUM(D48,D63,D69,D85,D105,D114,D120,D143,D158,D164,D173,D188,D194,D206,D212,D266,D272,D287,D293,D305,D323,D359,D371,D54,D91,D149,D179,D311) .... I dont see any issue with the formula.

Comment: @user3662369 - yup, there is no issue. But still, it is a good idea to write "test" in the merged cell and to try to display it. Once you succeed, replace it with the formula and try to display it again...

Comment: This is the code I have been trying to execute but getting listPrice as 0.0 .............................................................................................................Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(12).getCell(9);
 cell2Update.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
        
 Double listPrice = cell2Update.getNumericCellValue();

Comment: @user3662369 - Try with **test** instead of the formula. Then  try with `String listPrice` instead of `Double`. It can be that the decimal separator in your system is different than `.` and it does not parse to `Double`.